Error: No tests found. Make sure that arguments are regular expressions matching test files
Got this error when I tried to run the playwright test in my vs code -- "Error: No tests found. Make sure that arguments are regular expressions matching test files. You may need to escape symbols like "$" or "*" and quote the arguments."
Whenever I try to run a code or run the npx playwright test codegen in the VS Code, it's not working,

but if I try to use the already available example file, it's working.

I checked the Code of the file and it doesn't have any errors everything looks good and I uninstalled the playwright then installed it back and tried to run the test again but still hasn't worked as expected.
I just want this code to work in my VS Code playwright tool
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test'

test ('My First Test', async ({page}) => {

    await page.goto('https://google.com')
    await expect(page).toHaveTitle('Google')
    
});


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Also, Java != JavaScript. Always take a look at the docs before asking: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-test-match. This has already been asked and answered on this site as well: playwright 'no tests found.' on simple copy of example.spec.ts

Does this answer your question? playwright 'no tests found.' on simple copy of example.spec.ts

Your test files should be suffixed with either .spec.js or .test.js
So for your file, rename it to first.spec.js and run it.  It will work unless you have more issues in your playwright config.

There is a quick fix just replace \ with / and we are good to go.
Earlier – npx playwright test .\tests\demo
myfirsttest.spec.js
Now –  npx playwright test ./tests/demo/myfirsttest.spec.js
enter image description here

**To check the node -v and npm -v commands in your CMD and powershell terminal,

I checked in CMD its display the versions
Checked in powershell I faced the error**

C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1 is
not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about
running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

npm -v

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess





Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Run this 3 and 4 command in your poweshell terminal to fix this issue

check node -v and npm -v in powershell it will work good

finally Run your tests you wont get the error


"Error: No tests found. Make sure that arguments are regular expressions matching test files. You may need to escape symbols like "$" or "*" and quote the arguments."

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
